# Unity3d - LoadRawTextureData

Tags: c#, .net, image, algorithm, unity-game-engine

I'm recive jpg image byte data from server. It's byte data can be converted to image using `LoadImage` method. But this method is slow and work only in Unity3d main thread.

`LoadRawTextureData` - is fast, but required 'raw byte data'.

Raw data example:

```
byte[] pvrtcBytes = new byte[] {
            0x30, 0x32, 0x32, 0x32, 0xe7, 0x30, 0xaa, 0x7f, 0x32, 0x32, 0x32, 0x32, 0xf9, 0x40, 0xbc, 0x7f,
            0x03, 0x03, 0x03, 0x03, 0xf6, 0x30, 0x02, 0x05, 0x03, 0x03, 0x03, 0x03, 0xf4, 0x30, 0x03, 0x06,
            0x32, 0x32, 0x32, 0x32, 0xf7, 0x40, 0xaa, 0x7f, 0x32, 0xf2, 0x02, 0xa8, 0xe7, 0x30, 0xff, 0xff,
            0x03, 0x03, 0x03, 0xff, 0xe6, 0x40, 0x00, 0x0f, 0x00, 0xff, 0x00, 0xaa, 0xe9, 0x40, 0x9f, 0xff,
            0x5b, 0x03, 0x03, 0x03, 0xca, 0x6a, 0x0f, 0x30, 0x03, 0x03, 0x03, 0xff, 0xca, 0x68, 0x0f, 0x30,
            0xaa, 0x94, 0x90, 0x40, 0xba, 0x5b, 0xaf, 0x68, 0x40, 0x00, 0x00, 0xff, 0xca, 0x58, 0x0f, 0x20,
            0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xff, 0xe6, 0x40, 0x01, 0x2c, 0x00, 0xff, 0x00, 0xaa, 0xdb, 0x41, 0xff, 0xff,
            0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xff, 0xe8, 0x40, 0x01, 0x1c, 0x00, 0xff, 0x00, 0xaa, 0xbb, 0x40, 0xff, 0xff,
        };
```

How to convert non raw byte array to raw byte array?

PS: Unity 5.6.0f3

Comment: There is no 'raw byte data' data type. So you dont need to 'convert' your array. The method LoadRawTextureData accepts an byte array as a parameter.

Comment: I understand this. I'm search 'convert' method from jpeg byte[] to 'raw' byte[]

Comment: It's not possible to convert jpg to a raw bytes array in a fast way. Let me explain. The JPG format is compressed, it's bytes are not color information but a bunch of "pieces" that defines the image, losing a bit of the original information and quality in the process. In Unity, the LoadImage method will take whatever format you put there as image and convert to a texture (an array of colors) and obviously will take some time to do it while LoadRawTexture just skip the step of converting the image since it only allows already uncompressed raw data of colors for the image. Hope this helps.

Comment: @nosmirck but we can perform a transformation byte[] => color information outside the main thread. LoadImage - work only on main thread.

Comment: @МстиславПавлов with a large enough raw texture you'll have the same issue, the problem is not that the texture is compressed and takes time to load, your problem is that the LoadImage method runs in the main thread locking your frames. There is no solution as of today (August 2017) but there's a petition to add this feature: https://feedback.unity3d.com/suggestions/async-texture2d-dot-loadimage-and-other-texture-operations

Comment: @МстиславПавлов However, there's something you can do: Use Threads. Imagine you write a C# Class (not monobehavior, no UnityEngine libraries used, just plain simple C# class) called ImageLoader with a method like ImageLoader.LoadFromJPG("<path to your image>"); that returns byte[]. You could use a thread inside your gameobject's component like this: _t1 = new Thread(() => myByteImg = ImageLoader.LoadFromJPG("<path to your image>")); where myByteImg is a byte[] propety on your gameobject, then, on update or a coroutine that checks every few milliseconds you can check that myByteImg is not null

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no easy way to do it. The thread limit is pretty significant, and UnityEngine built in decoder can't easily be pushed to another thread. I experimented with using some third party code for decode/encode that could run in seperate thread, but in the end my results were insatisfactionary - C# Jpeg code was so much slower, that there was no benefit from threading. What you could do is write a C++ decoder plugin, that would just pass a pointer to decoded texture, that way you should be able to offload the main thread, but it can hardly be called easy